# is there any NFS implementation in C ?

Tags: c, nfs

I am working on my own implementation of NFS (Network File System ) in C. Are there any good available resources/ references that I can go through ? I do not know where do I begin from. I understand this is not quite the question one posts on stackoverflow since I have been  here before, but I really need to get started. I have undrstood the concept of NFS and how it actually works. Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Look at linux implementation of nfs

Comment: Honestly, i will have to code it in a linux environment. has to be in C programming though.

Comment: Is it a university project ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle: yes it is my university project. But we just have to implement NFS version 3. Stateless protocol not the one above that.

Comment: Do you need to implement it as a VFS module ?

Comment: you just should ask your professor, he is paid for this.

Comment: @JensGustedt: you think I didnt? I already did but all he has to say is this is a research project and is meant to be this vague. and he didnt provide much help. Although we keep pestering him.

Comment: @Mellowcandle: we need to build an NFS client basically. write the protocol for the client which interacts with the server. Thagts what we have been told

Comment: NFS has been available on linux since ~1994. And, last time I checked, it was *not* written in Pascal.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed above, the implementation needs to be a VFS extension module.
I suggest you read the VFS chapter in Understanding the linux kernel. The VFS is one of the most beautiful written code in the kernel. It is object oriented altough written in c, and the implementation of such an extension is not so hard.
Basically, you're given a structure of function pointers to commands such as open, write, etc. And you need to implement it.

Comment: So you mean to say that I should probably start writing some libraries pertaining to NFS that describe the protocol rules and related stuff, right ? Or am I thinking the other way round ?

Comment: @noobcoder: He ment you shall start by reading, not writing ... ;-)

Comment: I understand your point.